# Can't ssh through user with mounted via sshfs home dir

Tags: ssh, home-directory, sshfs

There are 2 users on *machine#0*: *user#0* and *user#1*. I can mount the desired dir from *user#0* on *machine#0* executing:

```
sshfs user@hostname:/home/folder /home/folder
```

The thing is that /home/folder has *some-path*/user#1 inside, which is home directory for *user#1*. But when I try to

```
ssh user1@machine0
```

After entering password it says
`Connection to machine0 closed.`
If I switch home of *user1* to another, local directory, I have no problems logging in. Why is this happening and how to make this work? Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked your logs?

Comment: I am sorry, what exactly do you mean by "checking logs" in this situation? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution.

1. In my case (embedded-linux), it was necessary to add *user1* to **aid_inet** and **aid_net_raw** groups in **/etc/group** file.
2. **allow_other** option had to be enabled when mounting fs, just like that:

   > sshfs user@hostname:/home/folder /home/folder -o allow_other

Thanks!